# fetch GeoJSON from Flask backend and use it in Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm working on an app that'll draw some shapes on a Google Maps map, using Flask as the backend. As a test, I'm trying to draw [these shapes](https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json) into my map. I have this simple function:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def receive_pos_data():


    r = requests.get('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json')

    return json.dumps(r.json())
```

And then I have this script to fetch it:

```
fetch('/test', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonPos,
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data_geojson => {
        // Handle the response from the server
        console.log('Server response:', data_geojson);

      })
      .then(data_geojson => map.data.loadGeoJson(data_geojson))
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
```

You can ignore its body, it's something for the future. Then, my InitMap function looks like this:

```
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: -28, lng: 137 },
  });


}
```

So, if I add the data directly through       `map.data.loadGeoJson("https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json");` it works no problem, but if I try to do it through the fetch requests, I get or:

```
util.js:231 

       GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/undefined 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

or

```
util.js:231 
        
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/[object%20Object] 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

If I do this instead:

```
fetch('/test', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: jsonPos,
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data_geojson => {
    // Handle the response from the server
    console.log('Server response:', data_geojson);
    map.data.loadGeoJson(data_geojson); // moved this inside the second then statement

  })
```

Internet says my JSON might be malformed, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

My desired output would be being able to plot this by fetching the geoJson from Python:

[image]

Which is what happens when I do `map.data.loadGeoJson("https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json");` directly on Javascript

Answer (score 0):

After some extra reading I found I had to use `addGeoJson` instead of `loadGeoJson` for local data. So, this works:

```
  fetch('/test', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonPos,
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data_geojson => {
        // Handle the response from the server
        // console.log('Server response:', data_geojson);
        map.data.addGeoJson(data_geojson);

      })

      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
```